# Commits done to view the KMZ file on Openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3

Before, I used Google Earth as a mapping but now I am trying to migrate to GE OpenLayers3.
commits can we do to show the KMZ file on Open layers3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Come on guys, is this a reception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unzip the KMZ with a library like [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/), and then to use the KML format to read uncompress data.

You can find [a working example](https://rawgit.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-extras-demos/master/kmz/demo-kmz.html) for this purpose (caution: it's a kmz calling other kmz ;) )

I repeat here the warning here I have in my github repo

> Demo depends from alerts provided by NOAA National
>   Weather Service at their Storm prediction center, so display can be
>   empty)

However, if demo does not show geometry, you can look the log in the console for learning purpose (KMZ uncompressed but just with no geometry)

Answer (score 1):

Be welcome to Openlayers. You can show KML on OL3 maps, so first [unzip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40944/can-i-convert-a-kmz-file-to-kml) your KMZ and see the [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/examples/).